# routing issue in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have issue in Routing in Mvc 4

My url goes like this

```
  http://localhost:portnumber/Session/View?Id=918&Pid=186
```

I want my url to be like this

```
  http://localhost:portnumber/Session/View/918/186
```

I have view like this

```
@Html.RouteLink("more..", "Default", new {Controller="Session",Action="View",Id=e.Id,Pid=e.Pid })

routes.MapRoute(
           name: "SessionView",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{Id}/{Pid}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Session", action = "view", Id = UrlParameter.Optional, Pid = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're not referring to the correct route.

In the routing table, you've added a route with the name "SessionView", but in your @Html.RouteLink, you refer to a route called "Default".

The correct call should be:

```
@Html.RouteLink("more..", "SessionView", new {Controller="Session",Action="View",Id=e.Id,Pid=e.Pid })
```

Answer (score 1):

Just try this

```
 @Html.ActionLink("more..", "View", "Session", new {Id=e.Id,Pid=e.Pid })
```

Description:

```
Html.ActionLink(<<LinkText>>, 
            "<<ActionMethod>>",  
            "<<Controller Name>>",
            new { Id=e.Id,Pid=e.Pid }, // <-- Route arguments.
            )
```